# Calculating calories for weighted treadmill wlaking

Tags: calories, walking, treadmill

I found a formula that incorporated duration, distance/speed, body weight and incline to calculate the number of calories burnt when using the treadmill. Is there a simple way to adjust that formula if I were to wear weights while walking? Could I just add that to the body weight, or would that be way off?

Comment: related: [Carrying 10kg while doing cardio](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24682/carrying-10kg-while-doing-cardio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good approximation, it will probably add a slight error but such a formula in itself is by necessity quite inaccurate.